# How to get a JavaScript "class" by invoking "new" from another "class"?

Tags: javascript, function, class

We can define a "class" In JavaScript by function, and get its "instance" by the "new" command. Just as follows:

```
function class_a() {
    this.tell = function () {
        console.log("This is a_class");
    }
}

function class_b() {
    this.tell = function () {
        console.log("This is b_class");
    }
}

var instance_a1 = new class_a();
var instance_b1 = new class_b();

instance_a1.tell();
instance_b1.tell();
```

My question is: Is there a way to generate these "classes" by the new command from another class? Just like this:

```
function typex(class_name)
{
    ...
}

var myclass_a = new typex("class_a");
var myclass_b = new typex("class_b");

var instance_a1 = new myclass_a();
var instance_b1 = new myclass_b();

instance_a1.tell();
instance_b1.tell();
```

Comment: Any function can be the target of a `new`, so make `typex` return a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the classes from typex but just as reference to the function itself (no invoking inside typex).

Option A: Private classes

```
function typex(class_name)
{
    function class_a() {
        this.tell = function () {
            console.log("This is a_class");
        }
    }

    function class_b() {
        this.tell = function () {
            console.log("This is b_class");
        }
    }
    if (class_name === "class_a")
            return class_a;
    if (class_name === "class_b")
            return class_b;
    throw new Error("unrecognized classname");
}
```

Option B: Public classes

```
function class_a() {
    this.tell = function () {
        console.log("This is a_class");
    }
}

function class_b() {
    this.tell = function () {
        console.log("This is b_class");
    }
}

function typex(class_name)
{
    if (class_name === "class_a")
            return class_a;
    if (class_name === "class_b")
            return class_b;
    throw new Error("unrecognized classname");
}
```

Then running the code:

```
var myclass_a = new typex("class_a");
var myclass_b = new typex("class_b");

var instance_a1 = new myclass_a();
var instance_b1 = new myclass_b();

instance_a1.tell();
instance_b1.tell();
```

Creates for both the output

```
This is a_class
This is b_class
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I end up NOT using the keyword `new` when calling `typex(...)`, bc I don't want whatever `new typex(...)` evalutes to to delegate its failed property lookups to `typex.prototype`.

Secondly, I capitalized `MyClass_A` and `MyClass_B` to indicate that they should be paired with the keyword `new`.

---

You could just have `typex` return a constructor function if that is the extent of your use case of these classes/instances.

```
function typex(class_name) {
  var classes = {};

  classes.class_a = function() {
    this.tell = function() {
      console.log('This is a_class');
    };
  };

  classes.class_b = function() {
    this.tell = function() {
      console.log('This is b_class');
    };
  };

  return classes[class_name];
}

var MyClass_A = typex("class_a");
var MyClass_B = typex("class_b");

var instance_a1 = new MyClass_A();
var instance_b1 = new MyClass_B();

instance_a1.tell(); // "This is class_a"
instance_b1.tell(); // "This is class_b"

instance_a1.constructor === instance_b1.constructor; // false (which is good)
```

Here's a heavily refactored version that reuses as much code and reduces memory usage as possible.

```
function typex(class_name) {
  var ClassConstructor = function() {
    this.class_name = class_name;
  };

  ClassConstructor.prototype.tell = function() {
    console.log('This is ' + this.class_name);
  };

  return ClassConstructor;
}

var MyClass_A = typex("class_a");
var MyClass_B = typex("class_b");

var instance_a1 = new MyClass_A();
var instance_b1 = new MyClass_B();

instance_a1.tell(); // "This is class_a"
instance_b1.tell(); // "This is class_b"

instance_a1.constructor === instance_b1.constructor; // false (which is good)
```